Power APPS - Adding Filter Functionality to Pie Charts Post Column Creation
Currently, I'm working on enhancing a Pie Chart in Power Apps by incorporating a filter. Specifically, I aim to filter the data based on a certain criterion.
To give you some context, I've created a pie chart utilizing data from a SharePoint list. The formula I've used counts the occurrences of each status in the list:
AddColumns(
AddColumns(
GroupBy(
AddColumns(
ShowColumns('MyList'),
"Status Type",
Status.Value
),
"Status Type",
Status_Group
),
"Status Count",
CountRows(ThisRecord.Status_Group)
),
"Label",
Concatenate('Status Type', " (", 'Status Count', ")")
)
Now, my objective is to incorporate a filter to display the status counts for a specific department.
In our SharePoint list, we have an additional Choice column named 'Department'. The goal is to modify the pie chart to only show data related to a selected department.
Do you have any insights or suggestions on how we can achieve this seamlessly? Your input would be greatly appreciated.
